# In PHP, how to make SQL query with @ in?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have problem. in my database, I have a column `email`. When I make SQL query I get following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com)' at line 1

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID_Dijak from dijak  WHERE (Email=".$mejl.")";
```

If I try to do query in php my admin it works if I put ' ' between my email, but how to do it in php? Thank you.

Comment: If you use proper parameters instead of munging the query string, then you will not have inadvertent syntax errors.

Comment: `quotes` will help. Enclose email value in quotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I made a mistake earlier... I tested this way and it should now work

`$sql='SELECT ID_Dijak from dijak WHERE (Email = "' . $mejl . '")';`

Comment: Not working, error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com . '%')' at line 1

Comment: whats the value of the variable $mejl  ?

Comment: email address, example@gmail.com

Comment: I will change my above

Comment: Still not working: Unknown column '$mejl' in 'where clause'

Comment: This is plain wrong. If OP did not want to parameterise the query, then the valid answer would be: `$sql = "SELECT ID_Dijak FROM dijak WHERE Email = '{$mejl}'";`. Quotes are placed around the email in the SQL query (because it is a string), and the `$meil` variable is interpolated so that it is evaluated by PHP.

Comment: Thank you tpunt, its working!

Answer (score 0):

take datatype varchar() for email

Comment: It is set to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a prepared statement in PHP, also to prevent injection attacks.

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT ID_Dijak from dijak WHERE Email=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $mejl);
$stmt->execute();
```